# Why is my rails insert slow even if I use thread?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use rails and Mysql as DB.I want to import mass history data from my old system using Mongo.

My rake task code is like this:

```
threads = []

File.foreach("file.json").each_slice(100) do |lines|
  threads << Thread.new {
    time = Time.now
    lines.each do |line|
      json = ... # Parse json
      Model.new(json).save!(validate: false)
    end
    p Time.now.to_f - time.to_f
  }
end
```

I tried with a json with 100 lines. Each thread costed 10s.
But when I tried with a json with 1000 lines. Each thread costed about 90s, and all cost about 90s.

Why didn't each thread still cost 10s when I import the json with 1000 lines?

And how to speedup it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bottleneck is the database, I suggest you bulk create your models.

Use [active-record-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to do this.

Example:

```
models = []
File.foreach("file.json").each_slice(100) do |lines|
  lines.each do |line|
    hash = #parse line here
    models << Model.new(hash)
  end
end
Model.import models
```